# Finding all bijections $f : \mathbb{N}^+ \to \mathbb{N}^+$ satisfying $a \mid b \Rightarrow f(a) \mid f(b)$

Tags: divisibility, order-theory, integers

Let $f$ be a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. We have two statements:

1. $\quad a \mid b \Leftrightarrow f(a) \mid f(b)$
2. $\quad a \mid b \Rightarrow f(a) \mid f(b)$

I have managed to find all bijections $f$ satisfying statement (1). They are precisely the functions defined as

\begin{equation*}
f(n) = \sigma(p_1)^{\alpha_1} \cdots \sigma(p_m)^{\alpha_m}
\end{equation*}

where $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_m^{\alpha_m}$ is the prime decomposition of $n$, and $\sigma$ is a permutation of the infinite set of prime numbers (i.e. $\sigma$ is a bijection between the set of prime numbers and itself.).

Now I want to find all bijections $f$ satisfying statement (2), but I couldn't make any significant progress. My conjecture is that there is no bijection satisfying (2) but not (1). An example of such a bijection would also be very good as a first step. Thanks for any help.

EDIT 1:
So far, I have proved some easy properties like the followings, but that's all. Let $f$ be a bijection satisfying statement (2), then we have

- $f(1) = 1$
- If $f(p)$ is prime, then $p$ is prime,
- If $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are relatively prime, then $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime,
- If $f$ satisfies $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$, then $f$ also satisfies statement (1).

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $f$ for (1). What does $f$ do if $n$ has got $m+1$ distinct prime factors?

Comment: @junjios The expression $p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_m ^ {\alpha_m}$ is defined to be the unique prime decomposition of $n$, so by definition, $n$ has $m$ distinct prime factors.

Comment: I know that but how do you choose your permutation? You can't just fix one permutation, say $\sigma\in S^m$ because it is not clear, what $f$ does on a number with $m+1$ prime factors. Sry, it also might just be me, being a bit stupid right now.

Comment: @junjios Oh, I see the disagreement now, $\sigma$ is not a permutation in $S^m$, instead $\sigma$ is a permutation of primes. That is to say, $\sigma$ is a bijection on the set of prime numbers.

Comment: @MetinErsinArıcan Thank you, that makes sense! In hindsight it is really quite clear if I read carefully.

Comment: I don't think there's any simple description of all the bijections satisfying (2).  Do you have a reason to think there is one?

Comment: @EricWofsey You seem to be implying that there are bijections satisfying (2) but not (1). Do you have a proof of that ?

Comment: @EricWofsey The only reason is that I couldn't find any bijection satisfying (2) but not (1). Such an example would be very good as a first step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't expect that there's any nice description of all the bijections that satisfy (2).  In particular, here is a procedure you can follow to construct lots of them.

We define $f$ on numbers one by one with the following restrictions (starting from $f(1)=1$).  First, don't define $f(n)$ until you've defined $f(m)$ for all divisors $m$ of $n$.  When defining $f(n)$, you pick some value that is a common multiple of the (already-chosen) values for $f(m)$ for divisors $m$ of $n$.  After doing so, for each divisor $d$ of $f(n)$ that is not yet in the image of $f$, pick some prime $p$ on which you have not yet defined $f$ and define $f(p)=d$.

In this way, you can define $f$ step-by-step such that in each step, the domain of $f$ is always a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}^+$ closed under taking divisors and its image is also closed under taking divisors.  You can also easily arrange in this process that every element of $\mathbb{N}^+$ is eventually in the domain of $f$ and eventually in the image, so in the end you get a bijection $\mathbb{N}^+\to\mathbb{N}^+$.  But also, $f$ can do all sorts of wild things.  For instance, you could start by defining $f(2)=30$, and then defining $f$ on a bunch of other primes to take values in all the divisors of $30$.  Then you could define $f(4)$ to be any multiple of $30$ at all.  Continuing in this way, you will have infinitely many opportunities to define $f$ to not just behave like a permutation of the primes.